# Search for and print only matched pattern

Tags: search, grep, xml, sed

I have some huge xml text files.  I need to write a script to find and print a specific tag only.  I tried `sed` and `grep` but they both return the whole line.

Using SunOS 5.x, so not all linux commands may work.  `grep -o` is not available.

The 'xml' file is not actually one huge xml document, but each line is a separate xml document, with just a few tags, not even nested.  And the structure is fairly easy, so full xml parsers is not needed, and probably would not work.

I was looking for `sed`, `awk`, or some other one liners, but could not get them to work, and they are both relatively new to me.

Comment: If you show an example line and the `sed` command you tried, we can come up with a `sed` command that should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a tool that's made for parsing XML files, however here is an example of how you might do that in `sed`:

Given a simple line like `<foo>bar</foo><baz>qux</baz>` and you want the value "bar" you can do this:

```
sed -e 's|.*<foo>\([^<]*\)</foo>.*|\1|' inputfile
```

Comment: Exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'xml sel' command of xmlstarlet: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

Example:

```
xml sel -t -c '/xpath/to/my/tag' xmlfile.xml
```

Beware of default namespace in your xml file though (read [this](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#d0e673)). An example:

```
xml sel -N x="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/" -t -m '//x:Param' -c "." -n /usr/lib/firefox-3.5/searchplugins/google.xml
```

I use xmlstarlet for all xml tasks now, mostly queries.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not permitted to install third party. And the script should be usable on any SunOS system without installing new progs

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo '<a><b>B</b><c>C</c></a>' > file.xml
$ perl -ne 'm!<b>(.*)</b>! && print "$1\n"' *.xml
B

$ perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/="<"}; print "$1\n" if m![bc]>([^<]+)<!' *.xml
B
C
```

But really you should use an XML parser for reasons that should be (or will become) all too obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

1. install grep from [sunfreeware.com](http://www.sunfreeware.com/). This should get you the -o option that you know from linux.
2. write a perl or python script to do the job.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not permitted to install third party.  And the script should be usable on any SunOS system without installing new progs.

Comment: check and see if you got perl or python installed. Then a script written by yourself should be pretty portable.